# Get Image Path from Gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I used picasso to load Images from my Activity.
I'm using this code to get all the images(path) from my Phone..

```
final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            IMAGES.add("file://" + imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));
        }
```

Is there any other way to do this? since mangedQUery is deprecated.
And is it possible to load this on AsyncTask?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? You want another method to select image in the phone gallery?

Comment: Yes. If there's more way to do this. If none, can i Put that code on AysncTask? because it takes time to start the activity because of getting the images path from my phone gallery.

Comment: Did the code help you? If yes, you can accept my answer, if not, tell me what is your problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have this code that works fine, it lets you choose a picture from gallery on a button click and put it in an imageview. I don't put xml, where you have to put a button and imageview. The button has : **onClick:loadImagefromGallery**

```
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;

    private EditText imageTitle;

    private Button button_selectpic;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_selectpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        button_selectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```